# Make charge with Stripe API

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I would like to use Stripe on Android App.
I can read docs and see samples.

I can see that samples show us that `Charge` should be done by 'our backend'
not by Android app.
but I had heard that client app should be possible to do payment without backend. I mean, directly to `Stripe`.
I saw old samples, where it was able to use `Charge` class from `android app`, but this class is not available now.

Can someone explain, what part should do `Charge`?
I mean, client or backend?

Answer (score 2):

Its a good approach to send token to your server for charge.The only part which should done at your end is collecting the token which you'll get by stripe api.
The reason behind all this is security and memory usage.As the sever has more memory comparatively app, its good to perform all computations there.